# How to authenticate API calls from MVC

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0

I have two projects in my solution (Web API type and MVC type). MVC project calls the APIs in API project. When i run the application i logged into the web. Now i want to authenticate the API calls in the API project using oAuth. How can i achieve this ? I have implemented the oAuth classes in the API project. Issue is that when i hit the URL for getting the token using username and password i get "invalid_grant" exception, which is obvious because my there is no log in in the API project. How can i do this ? From what i got from google is that i have to use "Password Credentials Flow". Can anyone provide me with the code for this

Comment: Please provide your authentication code. Also, are sending **grant_type=password** alongside the **username** and **password** in your login request?

Comment: i get login to web not to web api, this is the basic issue. When i ask for token by hitting the server/Token url with username and password in the body, i get invalid_grant exception. My basic issue is that how can i pass my user credentials from web to api

Comment: try putting this in your body: userName=XXX&password=XXX&grant_type=password

Comment: I dont have the username and password in api, its in the web

Comment: any code example of "Password Credentials Flow" ? @rad

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get what you mean by web exactly. What I expect to happen is that first you send the login request from your MVC project View to the Api project, then the Api project creates the token and sends it back to the MVC View as the response.

Comment: no. But this is the issue, i am unable to pass login credentials from MVC to API. What i googled is that "Password Credentials Flow" mechanism is used for this purpose. Can you kindly tell me how can i pass my credentials from MVC to API ?

Comment: Once you set up your you Api project on IIS or IIS Express (for local runs) you can call the Api methods from wherever you want. How are trying to call you api? Generally it's done using Ajax.